# Cannot set axis minimum to greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a diagram like so:

```
ax = df.plot(kind="bar", ylim=[1, 5])
```

Unfortunately, the y-axis still begins at zero.

```
ax.set_ylim([-5, -5])
```

...works as intended.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to set the limit directly when plotting.

Try any of the following, they should all work:

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([1, 5])
```

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1,x2,1,5))
```

```
plt.ylim((1,5))
```